# S3 website endpoint access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, acl

The [s3 website endpoint docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html) say:

> "In order for your customers to access content at the website
>   endpoint, you must make all your content publicly readable."

Does this mean:

- Configuring a bucket for website hosting automatically makes all of
  that bucket's content readable via the website endpoint (regardless
  of per object permissioning)

OR

- Per object permissioning can prevent specific content from being accessible via the website endpoint while other content is accessible via the website endpoint.

or some other explanation I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

Simply enabling the web site hosting feature does **not** implicitly make the entire bucket public.

The web site endpoint for the bucket does not support accessing private objects using pre-signed URLs or the `Authorization` header... so if you want to make objects accessible, you have to do it explicitly at either the object or bucket level, using ACLs or policy statements.

If you don't make them accessible, they remain inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

Two aspects here because there are two different ways you can give permissions to bucket,

- Bucket level permission (Permission for all files in the bucket)
- Object permission (permission for each file inside the bucket)

If you want bucket level permission then you have to create a bucket policy and in that bucket policy if you gave permission to all (Principal: "*") then everybody can access all files in the bucket. **Ideally, if you are hosting a static website in an S3 bucket then you should give full read-only permission to the public for all files. In this scenario, you can set a bucket level policy to give read-only permission to the public.**

Object level permission you can set by access control list and you can give it for each object in the bucket. For example, if you have 10 files in the bucket and you have given only two files public access then only that file can be accessed by public not the remaining ones